# Python - append to dictionary by name with multilevels 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2 (hierarchical)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, openpyxl

I use openpyxl to read data from excel files to provide a json file at the end. The problem is that I cannot figure out an algorithm to do a hierarchical organisation of the json (or python dictionary).

The data form is like the following:

[image: Table]

The output should be like this:

```
{
'id'       : '1',
'name'     : 'first',
'value'    : 10,
'children': [ {
                'id'   : '1.1',
                'name' : 'ab',
                'value': 25,
                'children' : [
                  {
                   'id'   : '1.1.1',
                   'name' : 'abc' ,
                   'value': 16,
                   'children' : []
                  }
                 ]
                },
              {
                'id' : '1.2',
                 ...
          ]
}
```

Here is what I have come up with, but i can't go beyond '1.1' because '1.1.1' and '1.1.1.1' and so on will be at the same level as 1.1.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re
from json import dumps

wb = load_workbook('resources.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.get_sheet_names()[0])
resources = {}
prev_dict = {}
list_rows = [ row for row in sheet.rows ]
for nrow in range(list_rows.__len__()):
    id = str(list_rows[nrow][0].value)
    val = {
    'id'        : id,
    'name'      : list_rows[nrow][1].value ,
    'value'     : list_rows[nrow][2].value ,
    'children'  : []
    }
    if id[:-2] == str(list_rows[nrow-1][0].value):
        prev_dict['children'].append(val)
    else:
        resources[nrow] = val
        prev_dict = resources[nrow]

print dumps(resources)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access your data by ID, so first step is to create a dictionary where the IDs are the keys. For easier data manipulation, string `"1.2.3"` is converted to `("1","2","3")` tuple. (Lists are not allowed as dict keys). This makes the computation of a parent key very easy (`key[:-1]`).

With this preparation, we could simply populate the children list of each item's parent. But before doing that a special ROOT element needs to be added. It is the parent of top-level items.

That's all. The code is below.

Note #1: It expects that every item has a parent. That's why `1.2.2` was added to the test data. If it is not the case, handle the `KeyError` where noted.

Note #2: The result is a list.

```
import json

testdata="""
1 first 20
1.1 ab 25
1.1.1 abc 16
1.2 cb 18
1.2.1 cbd 16
1.2.1.1 xyz 19
1.2.2 NEW -1
1.2.2.1 poz 40
1.2.2.2 pos 98
2 second 90
2.1 ezr 99
"""

datalist = [line.split() for line in testdata.split('\n') if line]
datadict = {tuple(item[0].split('.')): {
                'id': item[0],
                'name': item[1],
                'value': item[2],
                'children': []} 
            for item in datalist}
ROOT = ()
datadict[ROOT] = {'children': []} 
for key, value in datadict.items():
    if key != ROOT:
        datadict[key[:-1]]['children'].append(value)
        # KeyError = parent does not exist

result = datadict[ROOT]['children']
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```